# Discord bot missing 'Intents'

Tags: discord, python-3.9

I am currently trying to make a discord bot in python that responds to a command. When I run the code it prints

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Projects\disco bot\ppap", line 4, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

This is the code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('DiscordBotToken'))
```

how would I fix this?

I have looked up for a fix but nothing is working.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: Used the sample and now getting a   'TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead' in the terminal